# how to call mysql script in R under windows OS

Tags: sql, r

I have two .sql files that can organize data from a database and export them to a table in a mysql server. However, the database name will change for 100 different cases eg cAAAAAyBBBB AAAAA and BBBB will change for each case. I am trying to create a R script and will pass the database into .sql file and run or call the .sql file in R and loop over these cases.

Is there any way to do this?

for example in python under linux I can do,

```
for d in ddata:

count+=1

returnStatus = os.system("mysql --defaults-extra-file=user.cnf " + d + " < " + one.sql)  

if returnStatus!=0:
    print("Failed to load data for", d, "into database.")
```

Comment: See `?system`. The logic is the same. Construct a string and pass it to `system`. You have to have `mysql` installed and in your `PATH`.

Comment: I have another question, any format for user.cnf file?
Such as
hostname:
port:
username:
password:

Comment: If you are  calling a string on `system`, R doesn't care. It's up to your tool (mysql) how to format it.